# SQL LIKE %% show another rows

Tags: sql

If im use:

`` SELECT * FROM `iphone_colors` WHERE `cat_id` = 9 AND `models` LIKE '%_12_%' ``

Why i see *Graphite*, *Gold*, *Silver* and *Ocean* colors?
[image]

Comment: which db are you using? `_` is another type of wildcard in some dbs

Comment: Because your search is asking for anything that has "12" in model column and cat_id is 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The _ (underscore) character is a wildcard. It needs to be escaped ('\_') to be treated as a literal.

Try the following sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `iphone_colors` WHERE `cat_id` = 9 AND `models` LIKE '%\_12\_%'
```